# InvalidOperationException occurred while implementing Dependency Injection in ASP.NET Core app

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

As I am learning about Dependency Injection, so I have also shared my understanding (Please correct me wherever you guys feel to do so). The concept behind the following sample is to check the advantage of using Dependency Injection as it helps in implementing loose coupling in the application which will further prevent me from making lots of changes in the project in the case when concrete definitions (*classes*) tend to change in future.

**IEmailService** - Interface:

```
public interface IEmailService
{
    void SendMail();
}
```

**EmailService** - Class inheriting above interface

```
public class EmailService : IEmailService
{
    public EmailService(string emailFrom, string emailTo)
    {

    }

    public void SendMail()
    {
        // Code here 
    }
}
```

**HomeController**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IEmailService _service;

    public HomeController(IEmailService service)
    {
       _service = service;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        _service.SendMail();
        return View();
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   // Add framework services.
   ...
   services.AddTransient<IEmailService, EmailService>();
   ...
}
```

**Practical assumption**

I assume that earlier there was no parameterized constructor in the *EmailService* class, but in future, I feel like I need to add a parameterized constructor but it shouldn't have an impact on those controllers (like *HomeController*) which are using abstraction (*interfaces*) to access them indirectly.

Unfortunately, when I am running the above code, I am getting the following exception which seems to disappear if I am removing the parameterized constructor from *EmailService* class.

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.String' while attempting to activate 'DependencyInjectionDemo.Services.EmailService'.

Comment: I would move `string emailFrom, string emailTo` to `SendMail()` method, since this looks more like the method's responsibility. Then DI will work again. Also, everything that you want DI framework to inject should be registered in `ConfigureServices`

Comment: Good point @Ignas :) but suppose there are global variables defined in the class EmailService which need to be initialized within the constructor. By the way, this code is just for learning purpose. So I am trying to find the right way to encounter such issues, instead of finding a workaround.

Comment: "As I am learning about Dependency Injection". Pro tip: read [this introductionary chapter](https://manning-content.s3.amazonaws.com/download/7/f7d17b7-f62d-4dcd-9bc7-8a261e6aa4a8/Seemann2_DEidotNET2E_MEAP_V01_ch1.pdf) of THE book about Dependency Injection.

Comment: Thanks @Steven, I will check it out :)

Comment: If you are looking for a way to play more with DI, you can add something like `IHtmlRenderer` etc. to your `EmailService` constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can register your `EmailService` using a lambda:

```
services.AddTransient<IEmailService>(_ => new EmailService("from@", "to@"));
```

`emailFrom` and `emailTo` however seem *runtime data*, which means that the Controller might be responsible of supplying this information to the `IEmailService`. Since the `EmailService` is *decoupled* from the controller, it means that the controller is not responsible of its creation.

In general, you should prevent needing to initialize your components (`EmailService` in your case) with runtime data, as explained [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99), the advice is:

> *Don't inject runtime data into application components during construction; it causes ambiguity, complicates the composition root with an extra responsibility and makes it extraordinarily hard to verify the correctness of your DI configuration. My advice is to let runtime data flow through the method calls of constructed object graphs.*

In your case this basically means changing the `IEmailService` abstraction to the following:

```
public interface IEmailService
{
    void SendMail(string emailFrom, string emailTo);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment :).Meanwhile, I am getting what all you have suggested to me. Can you please redirect me to a practical example where interfaces help in minimal code maintainability (actually what I was trying to achieve in my sample code above) using DI in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: @AjendraPrasad: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Your own question is a practical minimal example of where interfaces help. The `IEmailService` is a practical example.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear to you. What I was trying to say is that when I am injecting IEmailService in my HomeController, how the actual implementation in EmailService could change (if it is not by adding parameterized constructor at least) to get me feel like thank god I used DI for loose coupling and hence I don't need to change my code due to changes in concrete class definition. Hope you got it :)

Comment: your suggestion perfectly answered my question, as far as it is about to see a clear advantage of using DI, I found this link

http://www.codearsenal.net/2015/03/c-sharp-dependency-injection-simple.html#.WR2Qx-uGOM8